# How to assert a CSS attribute contains some text in Cypress test?

Tags: css, cypress

In my Cypress test I'm trying to assert that an element's text is underlined.

I tried to use the below assertion:

```
homePage.getHeadingWidgetContent().should('have.css', 'text-decoration', 'underline');
```

But the actual `text-decoration` is `'underline solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)');`

This below assertion passes:

```
homePage.getHeadingWidgetContent().should('have.css', 'text-decoration', 'underline solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)');
```

Is there a way I can assert that `text-decoration` ***includes*** 'underline'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`text-decoration` is shorthand for a group of properties. You should use one of its [constituent properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration#constituent_properties), specifically `text-decoration-line`.

```
homePage.getHeadingWidgetContent().should(
  'have.css', 'text-decoration-line', 'underline'
);
```